# Upper and lower bound - Digital electronics

Tags: digital-logic, logic-level

A logic signal is transmitted in a logic circuit with positive logic, where \$V_{IL}=2.3 V\$, \$V_{IH}=4.5 V\$, \$V_{OL}=1.4 V\$, and \$N_{MH}= 1.8 V\$ . Recall that when using positive logic, the higher-amplitude range represents a 1 while the lower-amplitude range represents a 0. Use the figure to determine the lower and upper bounds of the undefined region for the output.

I calculated 0.9V for the lower bound, and 6.3V for the upper, but these are wrong.

[image]

Comment: What is your Vdd?

Comment: The lower bound is already given by V_OL.

Answer (score 1):

Here, your calculation seems to be correct,

`VIL - VOL = NML`
`VOH - VIH = NMH`, from your calculation, `NML = 2.3 V - 1.4 V = 0.9 V` and 
`1.8 V (NMH) = VOH - 4.5 V`, so `VOH = 6.3`

From your valuation we can say that, If `Vdd` is 5 V then VOH can't be 6.3. See Image and interpret accordingly.

[image]